# Minim library in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, processing, minim, processing-ide

I programmed a sketch that uses Minim with the Processing IDE.  Everything is working fine.

I'm now planning to improve it, and moved to Eclipse, as I have done with many other projects.  I configured the build path to include minim.jar.  All the imports seem to work fine.  But I can't compile the project because I get the following error when I initialize de Minim instance varialbe:

> The constructor Minim(PApplet) is undefined

The declaration gives no error, so I reckon the library loads fine.  The exact same code works in the processing IDE but not in Eclipse.  Here's my code:

```java
import processing.core.*;
import ddf.minim.*;
import ddf.minim.signals.*;
import ddf.minim.analysis.*;
import ddf.minim.effects.*;

public class MinimTest extends PApplet {    
    Minim minim;    
    public void setup() {
        minim = new Minim(this); // error in this line
    }
}
```

I don't have a clue on what's going on.  Any pointers will be very much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you add all the .jar files used by the Minim library to the source path:

```
jl1.0.jar       minim.jar       tritonus_share.jar
jsminim.jar     mp3spi1.9.4.jar
minim-spi.jar       tritonus_aos.jar
```

It should compile fine after that

Comment: I just tried it.  Still getting the error:  Multiple markers at this line
 - The constructor Minim(PApplet) is 
  undefined
 - solve error problem and connect to main 
  class

Comment: I wouldn't've posted unless I've tested and it worked :) Can you try [my project](lifesine.eu/so/MinimTest.zip) ?

Comment: I'm sure you wouldn't have :)  It works!  I found out that the problem was in my minim.jar library.  It must've been corrupted or something, because just substituting it by yours made it work.  THANK YOU very very much!  You made my day.

Comment: No worries! Feel free to vote, mark the answer as you find suitable ;)